# Mapping algorithm of subjects

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to make a system that assesses students' exams to learn their weaknesses. The exam consists of all subjects on their syllabus.

How do I --

1. Measure the skill of a student based on his/her score on the exam
2. Extract from the exam the topics on which the student performed poorly

My question is what algorithm should I use to map the syllabus based on the incorrect answers. Please help me. I'm new to this.

**Update:**
The **input** would be their exam with their answer and the **output** would be their knowledge level and suggestion of which topic should they study more

If you need more information please ask, i really need to know what algorithm should i use.

Comment: This looks to me like it is too broad a question for stackoverflow. If you added more details including example input and output data, a description of what you've thought of so far, and some specific questions that relate to *programming*, you would have more chance of getting some good answers.

Comment: for the first one, o thought of using JESS for the evaluation of their knowledge level as a `rule-based system` but for mapping the incorrect answer to the syllabus i have no idea of how would i do that

Comment: On a programming level or a design and problem solving level? If you are looking for a preexisting algorithm it will be find-able once you come up with specific idea + search terms.

Comment: Design level is what i lack now, I already search over the internet, but still no luck. I only have assumption. I thought of using decision tree and classification algorithms but i can't support my thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple system consists of tagging each question with one or more topics, then tallying the correct answers, sort by percentage, and output e.g. `You got 3/8 (38%) of StackOverflow questions right`

Answer (score 0):

I notice you haven't tagged a specific language, so I'll outline the way I would do it in Python.

Could you not have a `dict` (this is composed of a a key - this could be the subject, and a corresponding value - this could be the exam result).

You could then sort the dict by values, in order from high to low. The best subjects would be  at the top and the worst at the bottom.

If you're not using Python, you could use the Map type from C++ instead.

Comment: Sorry but i need it in java i forgot to tag java.

Comment: I think there is a similar Map object available in java.util